# Automatic Wrapper/Interface generation for C#

Tags: c#, c++, code-generation, wrapper, unmanaged

In our Project we use a GIS library written in C++ with a C# Wrapper layer on top. As we do TDD we would like to be able to stub those components out. For the stub generation we use MS Fakes and for the majority of the wrapper classes we can create stubs. But there are some classes in the C# Wrapper that uses unsafe code with Pointers. For this classes MS Fakes cannot generate stubs as it does not support unmanaged code.
I think one way to solve this issue would be to generate another C# wrapper layer from the existing one that does not contain any unsafe code. Does anyone know a tool which could do this? Or maybe there's another good way to achieve it.